# iOS & Parse Push Notification - iPhone 5s/c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, push-notification

I have set up push notifications for my app. It's week working great for weeks. I recently upgraded my iPhone 5c, iPhone 5 to iOS 8.4.1 (latest). Since the upgrade push notifications have stopped working. I know push notifications work because I have an iPhone 6 and push notifications work as they should.

I have tried using my iPhone 5s to send a message to another account (iPhone 6). The iPhone 6 does receive the push notification...when I do the opposite, the iPhone 5s  does not receive the push notification.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue? I looked online at some apple/parse communities but haven't been able to find a fix.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Best,

Comment: Did you properly ask to accept notifications for that device through the app? After that, did you properly send the tokenID for that device to parse?

Comment: @Yarneo yes i did. It registers the device in Installations. When i do a test via Parse Web Interface only the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 pluses receive the push notifications.

Comment: and you are online with the new phone? I am sure you are, but it sounds weird if it is the phone's fault that it cannot receive pushes...

Comment: Just for clarity: `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is never called in appDelegate when you run the code in a iPhone 5, 5c, and 5s?

Comment: good question let me check

Comment: @Yarneo I have finally figured out my problem....well at least i know what it is. I'm able to send and receive push notifications when do a build on my iphones directly from my mac. It does not work when I use TestFlight. I am using two different certificates for push one for Dev and one for Prod.

Comment: I figured it out - I was missing a Push Production Certificate (.p12) - forgot I only had one for development. This fixed my issue.

Comment: @Ronaldoh1 That is great to hear! The push notifications for Apple isn't the most friendly to say the least. Good luck!

Comment: Same problem here. However i have my .p12 configured properly. i don't know what might be..

Comment: @HugoVanderlei ive become an expert with push notifications lol let me

Comment: Let me know the error and steps youve completed

Comment: I'm not getting any error, i just don't receive any notification, i'm testing on my iPhone 5

Comment: @HugoVanderlei ok cool the .p12 certificates have to be created for both Dev and Prod ...you need both if you're trying to put this up on app store and if you're using Test Flight to test it on your iOS Devices. Also, I'm assuming you're using parse - you need to upload these files under push settings. 1 thing to note is that push notifications will not work on simulator.

Comment: @Ronaldoh1 I've added the Dev certificate on Parse and now It worked! thanks! I was only adding the prod certificate, that's why i wasn't receiving any notifications on developer environment

Comment: @HugoVanderlei great! Push notifications can be a pain.